# stuck at asking for CAMERA_ROLL permission. getting error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.Permission.askAsync')

Tags: react-native, expo

getting this warning (Almost an error, because app stuck at this point with showing yellow warning) while asking for the permission in react-native. Below is my code

```
//MY IMPORTS

import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';


//My CODE

onImageUpload = async () => {

    const {status, permissions} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    try {

        if (status === 'granted') {
            console.log("granted!!")
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('onImageUpload error:' + err.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have installed the module correctly. Perform the installation command from the command.

you'll need to run `expo install expo-permissions`

Comment: @MDB What is your version of the Expo?

Comment: @ hong develop my expo version is 35.0.0

Comment: Are there any parts of the code that import permissions from the Expo?

Comment: No only this line, `const {status, permissions} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);`